# Overload relay nameplate

Tags: motor, protection

The following information appears on the nameplate / description of an existing thermal overload relay (for motor protection) I need to replace with a modern unit of same functionality:

---

IEC 292-1 660V 3 PH AUX Ith 10A 500V ~ max

### 600V a.c. max Aux. H.D.

Can someone please explain to me in simple terms what each of these terms mean?

Answer (score 1):

IEC 292-1 is the name of a specification it was designed to follow.  A Google search for IEC 292-1 finds several parts you could look at to see if any of them are suitable replacements.

660V means that the maximum peak voltage it was designed for is 660 volts.

3 PH means that it is for a 3 phase motor.  Suitable power for such motors is often found in factories and in large stores, but rarely in homes.

AUX is probably an abbreviation for auxiliary.

Ith does not have an obvious meaning.

10A means that the allowed current is 10 amperes.

500V ~ max probably means that the maximum nominal input voltage is 500 volts AC.

600V a.c. max means that an input voltage of 600 volts AC is allowed, even if higher than recommended.

Aux. is probably an abbreviation for auxiliary.

H.D. does not have an obvious meaning.

Comment: Heavy Duty (use)? maybe? Just a guess.

Comment: Ith means that the 10A protection is a thermal protection.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use an Eaton PKZM0-10 which has basically the same specifications. But it can depend on your motor. If you need the auxiliary contact they have either an option part.

What kind of motor is connected to this protection device? As this is normally the way to select these kind of components.